# Listview inside UserControl raises full postback

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, updatepanel, postback

I have UserControl and within that control i have asp:ListView. Inside the ListView i have a asp:LinkButton. When i click on the LinkButton the control raises full postback, no matter if the UserControl is inside UpdatePanel or is not.

UserControl:

```
<asp:ListView ID="lvImages" runat="server" OnItemCommand="lvImages_ItemCommand">
     <ItemTemplate>
        <div>
               <asp:Image runat="server" ID="imgImageThumb" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("Image") %>' GenerateEmptyAlternateText="true" />
               <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lbtnImageAdd" CommandName="Add" CommandArgument='<%#Container.DisplayIndex %>'
                                    CausesValidation="false" Text="Add" />  
        </div>
     <ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Page:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="up" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
           <cuc:UserControl ID="cucUserControl" runat=server/>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the properties to let the update panel know what to trigger off of.  Try setting ChildrenAsTrigger=true.

Comment: I have tried that before, but the control stil raised full postback.

Comment: ChildrenAsTrigger has true set as a default.